# How fix this error: kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I have the following structure of files:

- execute.rb
- lib

  - my_class.rb

In the execute.rb I have the code bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'lib/my_class'

my_object= MyClass.new

my_object.some_method
```

And this is the code of my_class.rb:

```
class MyClass
    def some_method
        puts 'OK'
    end
end
```

So, I tried run the execute.rb:

```
ruby execute.rb
```

But I receive this error:

```
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- lib/my_class (LoadError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from execute.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me? I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `require_relative` instead of `require`. This was changed in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Ruby 2.1.7 worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fix this following the hint of @Dogbert.

At execute.rb code it's necessary replace:

```
require 'lib/my_class'
```

for:

```
require_relative 'lib/my_class'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. You could also use load 'lib/my_class.rb'
require_relative assumes the .rb suffix and so, you don't have to write it out. load requires the whole full filename.